# How to change toggleswitch's button style like in the light theme?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, expression-blend

I want to make it like this:

[image]

However, when I use dark theme, my ToggleSwitch looks like

[image]

Is it possible to define that ToggleSwitch should use light theme style? Or how should I change my ToggleSwitch style to get button like on the first picture?

I think, code is not important, because now it's just like a template copy (because it looks like default but with another background).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the correct color from Pre-defined phone resources:

in xaml you can access to :

```
<Rectangle Stroke="{StaticResource PhoneContrastBackgroundColor}" />
```

So you will see the black color in light theme and wihe color in black theme.